# Error installing pandas-datareader on PyCharm ( libxml2 missing )

Tags: python, pycharm, package, installation

I've installed pandas-datareader on cmd, but somehow when i try to install it in my pycharm project, i get this error : [image]

Edit: I've been looking around, tried the manual installation of libxml2 by dropping what i found to be a 2015 v. in my python LIB folder, but to no avail, i've checked all the similar questions on stackoverflow and tried most of them without success. I'm pretty sure I lack knowledge in order to process the right solution correctly. I'm feeling a bit helpless at this point...

What i've tried before the edit :

1. Simply installing lmxl but it is already installed.
2. Installing the libxml2 package in pycharm (got this error : non zero exit code, failed to find headers for libxml2: update includes_dir)
3. To install libxml2 but to no avail as i dont know how to handle manual installations(i found the index etc which is quite obscure to my knowledge)

Thank you all for reading.
If there's anything I can do to make the situation clearer, please tell me so.

Answer (score 0):

I run PyCharm as "Administrator" in Windows 10. Then it loaded requests-html without any issue. Please make sure you update "pip" as well.